# How to receive broadcast when application not installed

Tags: android, permissions, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

In my app I try to install .apk files by this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

but for some reasons, which I don't know, for some .apk files, android cannot install it. How can I subscribe to receive broadcast of this event?

Comment: may be once you get result back, can check for particular package name is installed or not.

Comment: @MKJParekh  So in this case my question is changing to how can I subscribe to receive broadcast of error results of installation?